# NPM throws code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME. Invalid package name "functional-red-base.$black-tree": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "functional-red-base.$black-tree": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aarshpatel/.npm/_logs/2022-04-24T11_14_36_953Z-debug-0.log
```

Keep getting this error message on all NPM installs. First I was trying to install Material UI. It did not work. Then I tried installing Chakra-UI, Still did not work.
I thought of clearing the NPM caching, Still the same error.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? `functional-red-base.$black-tree` is not an URL-friendly name.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, it's because the installation was interrupted (due to connection or something else).
first clean your npm cash by following command:

```
npm cache clean –force
```

then go to package.json and clear the invalid package directory name (**in your case "functional-red-base.$black-tree"**) only by deleting the name of package.

Answer (score -3):

Check your `package.json` to see if there's a line with this package name inserted during file creation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).